# Two computers, one Box folder - how do I configure Create React App?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a windows computer and a mac - both connected to the same Box folder. I had created create-react-app and have an app in the box folder. When I use the second computer I am not sure how to continue - the second computer has node installed globally, i even did "npx create-react-app" but "yarn start" or "npm start" would not work on the second computer. How do I configure the existing React app on the second computer?

Comment: Is npm, npx, or yarn, installed on your second computer?

Comment: node and npm are installed in the second computer. don't want to run "npx create-react-app my-new-app" on the folder I am already working on (from first computer) that has the node packages etc from create-react-app execution on first computer.